# Upload new ipython notebook to wakari

Tags: scipy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am not sure if this question is too specific to Wakari, but I figured I would give it a shot since there are a number of Wakari related posts on stackoverflow now. The question was this. Does anyone know how to upload an ipython notebook from your desktop pc to Wakari? I have a notebook that I have developed on my pc and I want to share it through Wakari. Do I have to manually copy all of the stuff from the notebook to the Wakari ipython notebook, or can I just upload the notebook file . . . ? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is just for data files (not notebooks), but you can upload files according to this:
https://www.wakari.io/docs/data.html#upload

If your local copy is in a git repo, it would be easy to push it to github and then access it from there:
https://www.wakari.io/docs/accessing.html